# Через 5-ю точку подключаются стили или bootstrap в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Короче, решил перенести шаблон на yii2, стили подключил а подгружается все по-другому 
Картники:  То что должно получится картинка 1 [image: То что должно получится картинка 1]
Что получается
[image: Что получается]
В AppAsset стили подключены

Comment: Покажите код для `AppAsset` и то, как вы его (`AppAsset`) подключаете в шаблоне. Также покажите итоговый код (из браузера), который генерируется после конечно загрузки страницы

Comment: `код`class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/style.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/script.js',
        'js/main.js'
    ];

Comment: А в шаблоне никак не подключается

Comment: Покажите, что выдает браузер при нажатии F12?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>My Yii Application</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="QDXkfv5vDrs92XbxFkECL5MVDleDhLH2Ur7C44cjRh15AqwNmhpa8FjuQINecjcZpl1mAeLCxJQQ1Luk3Wh0Ug==">

<link href="/web/assets/eb89c09f/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/web/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
<header> а скрины прикрепить нельзя

Comment: Попробуйте через F12 пройти по ссылке в `<link href="/web/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`. Она открывается для просмотра или пишет ошибку, что файл не найден?

Comment: Открывается для просмотра

Comment: Тогда, вероятней всего, у вас как-то нарушена `html` структура итоговая. Возможно из-за работы определенных виджетов. Стили написаны на одну классовую и id-шную стуктуру с наследованием, а итоговая отличается

Comment: В Yii вшит бутстрап 3, если для меню вы используете юишный виджет, у него могут отличаться стили вложенности.